# When to use Asymmetric Keys vs. Digital Certificate

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

We have a requirement where we need to be able to encrypt/decrypt the query string as below:

http://oursite.com/login?uname=**encryptedUName**&fname=**encryptedFname**&lname=**encryptedLname**.

The way it works is that our company supplies the CSV of records to third party vendors. The third party vendors then generated the above url and sends to the customer by email marketing.

So, I'm thinking of

1. encrypting the records in CSV file
2. Third party vendors just parses the encrypted text and generates the email.
3. When user click on link the user comes to our site.
4. We then decrypt and prepopulate the form fields.

The file content may  look like below:

*login?uname=**encryptedUName**&fname=**encryptedFname**&lname=**encryptedLname**.

login?uname=**encryptedUName**&fname=**encryptedFname**&lname=**encryptedLname**.*

Questions:

1. Should I use X509 certificate to encrypt and decrypt?
2. Or, should I use RSA?
3. How do I determine whether X509 or RSA?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A digital certificate works on top of a public & private key pair (asymmetric encryption). What a certificate adds is *trust*.You can sign a certificate using Certificate Authorities and create a trust chain.

In your case it doesn't seem as though you would need a certificate because you manage the encryption/decryption by yourself and your vendors know you and don't need a third party to verify you are who you say you are.

But, you may use a self-signed certificate as a key container if it's simpler for your vendors.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please suggest how do we manage the public key and private key using Asymmetric option? How do we share public key.

Comment: @Myagdi Whichever way you want, just keep the private one private. It could be in your application if you distribute one or on your web site